# Need procedure to install PEAR (over old version) with go-pear.phar on redhat, centos with php5.3

Tags: php, installation, pear, phar

I'm on CentOS and 
So far I've been reading about go-pear and go-pear.phar since my PEAR seems to have gotten behind enough that it can't be upgraded with command:  > pear upgrade PEAR

OK, reviews on go-pear.phar seem good, and maybe working with packages and signatures is a necessity.  Running on faith here, and forging ahead, I wonder...
Should I remove all of the previous PEAR packages, and if so what is the best way 
( hmmmm  'rm'  comes to mind ) 
I'm actually not trying to be an pioneer here;  Looking for someone who has done this ( In a controlled manner, and With a Positive Outcome ) ie:  I don't want to botch my Server Box.

What else will I need to know about locations (/usr/share) and php.ini file configuration. 
I'm open to PEAR install tips, with .phar and want to learn more about it.
Suggestions and pointers welcome.  TIA (thanks in advance)

Comment: Which php5.3 package are you using?

Comment: Please post the errors you get when doing "pear upgrade pear". it's always possible to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

This problem should be solved with RHEL in order to be solved in CentOS, here is the bug report about that problem:
[PHP53 Lacks php53-pear](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=673521)

Install the older php-pear via `yum install php-pear` and than run the following commands:

```
pear upgrade --force Console_Getopt
pear upgrade --force pear
pear upgrade-all
```

(It seems that these commands will solve the issue, it worked for *labradort* from the linked bug report and it worked for me)